# asp.net mvc api json wrapper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I Have an asp.net mvc api controller method that has a List as its return method. When called it returns this json data:

```
[
  {
    "AreaName": null,
    "AreaId": 0,
    "DestinationName": "Alanya",
    "DestinationId": 14,
    "CountryName": "Tyrkiet",
    "CountryId": 15
  },
  {
    "AreaName": null,
    "AreaId": 0,
    "DestinationName": "Antalya",
    "DestinationId": 113,
    "CountryName": "Tyrkiet",
    "CountryId": 15
  }
]
```

Earlier when I had this method in an asp.net mvc it would look similar to this:

earlier json data:

```
{
    "ContentEncoding":{
    "IsSingleByte":true,
    "BodyName":"iso-8859-1",
    "EncodingName":"Western European (Windows)",
    "HeaderName":"Windows-1252",
    "WebName":"Windows- 1252",
    "WindowsCodePage":1252,
    "IsBrowserDisplay":true,
    "IsBrowserSave":true,
    "IsMailNewsDisplay":true,
    "IsMailNewsSave":true,
    "EncoderFallback":{
        "MaxCharCount":1
    },
    "DecoderFallback":{
        "MaxCharCount":1
    },
    "IsReadOnly":true,
    "CodePage":1252
},
"ContentType":"application/json;",
"Data":
```

and then the above list would be added inside of the Data wrapper

My question is - how do I get this "wrapper" format back when using the asp.net mvc web api ?

Comment: Just curious why you need it when that returned object is a valid json already?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a normal format for list of objects and the second one, older represents an object. So when you need it - just return object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in the older version (normal mvc) you did return something like this:

```
return JsonResult(new { Data = myList });
```

now, in WebApi, you do this:

```
return myList;
```

That explains why the old result has all that formatting around. To get back the old wrapper in your WebApi, I guess you would simply do something like this:

```
return new { Data = myList };
```

If the above does not work, try the following:

1. Change the return type of your method to `HttpResponseMessage`
2. use this:

   `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Data = myList });`

I don't have anything to debug at the moment but both of the above should work. If they don't, it is probably because the serialization-deserialization does not like anonymous objects (this may give you more problems with XML than JSON actually).

Anyway, in my opinion it is a lot easier to live with the new version of your object, mainly because it does NOT have a (noisy) wrapper around :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own returning type, something like this:

```
public class InvoiceResult
{
    public int numberResultTotal;
    public int numberResultPaged;
    public List<InvoiceDTO> results;
}
```

ASP.NET Web API will convert it to JSON, XML or any other format and your client will get something like this:

```
<InvoiceResult>
<numberResultPaged>20</numberResultPaged>
<numberResultTotal>999999</numberResultTotal>
<results>
<InvoiceDTO>
<ID>110</ID>
<Active>2</Active>
<Date>01/01/2010</Date>
</InvoiceDTO>
<InvoiceDTO>...</InvoiceDTO>
<InvoiceDTO>...</InvoiceDTO>
<InvoiceDTO>...</InvoiceDTO>
</results>
</InvoiceResult>
```